# Project not working after copiyng it from another computer

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I changed my computer recently, and i copied my Angular projects to the new one, when i got in project folder and run the command:

```
ng serve --open
```

I had the error:

```
** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200 **
10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 activeinternal/child_process.js:319            
throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
^

Error: spawn EACCES
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
at module.exports (/localdata/hasanh/Documents/websites/Angular tests/BooksStore/node_modules/opn/index.js:75:24)
at Server.server.listen (/localdata/hasanh/Documents/websites/Angular tests/BooksStore/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:169:21)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
at emitListeningNT (net.js:1286:10)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

But with command:

```
npm start
```

the project works normally, i tried to do

```
npm install
npm serve --open
```

in the project folder but still not working?

Thanks for your Help

GR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, it works with the command:

```
ng serve --port=8181
```

Regards
Gr

Answer (score 0):

Following solutions you can try :

1. You can try to change your port number

   "start": "live-server --port=8181"
2. Try to install by using sudo

   sudo npm install

   sudo npm serve --open